# values of an array set to 0

Tags: python, numpy

I wrote this function (used later to select elite species in the genetic algorithm) to select k best values out of n, where not all n values are unique. First of all, I'd massively appreciate any comments to the code, but I'm primarily concerned with the fact that for some reason values in second vector (var2) are also set to 0. If instead of array I use list, this doesn't happen, but of course I want to use arrays rather than lists! So any comments are very welcome

```
import numpy

import tkMessageBox


'v1 is the vector of values from which k best must be selected for maximization problems'

class kbest():

    def val_report(self,k,v1):
        n=len(v1);
        v1=numpy.asarray(v1)
        v2=numpy.zeros(k)
        v2=numpy.asarray(v2,int)
        if k>n:
            self.trigger1()
        else:
            l=0; 
            while (l<k):
                best_now=numpy.asarray(numpy.where(v1==max(v1)),int)[0,0]
                v2[l]=best_now;
                v1[best_now]=0
                'v1=numpy.delete(v1, best_now)'
                'print l,v2;'
                l=l+1;
        return v2

    def trigger1(self):
        tkMessageBox.showwarning('Wrong value','Select the correct value')



var1=numpy.asarray(numpy.random.randint(0,100,10));

var2=var1

var3=numpy.asarray([1,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])

elite=kbest().val_report(3, var1);   

print elite

print var2
```

Comment: There's a lot of unnecessary stuff in here. I hope someone else will answer your question, but many people (such as myself) aren't going to read something that has unnecessary complexity such as GUI code that has nothing to do with your question or commented out lines. Coding according to regular Python standards would also make this more useful. See [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: Much of `val_report` (the second through fourth lines and everything in the `else` block) can be replaced with `v2 = numpy.argsort(v1)[-k:][::-1]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are just giving `var1` the alias `var2`. They both point to the same content.

You must copy the content over to a new object.

```
In [1]: x = numpy.arange(5)

In [2]: x
Out[2]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

In [3]: y = x.copy()

In [4]: x[:] = 0

In [5]: x
Out[5]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

In [6]: y
Out[6]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: The terminology here is a bit wonky, but this is exactly the issue.